# SqlDataReader and select don't work properly

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2014

VB.NET and SQL Server 2014. This piece of code produce a weird error. `HasRows` is TRUE but the selection is empty and, more the this, the selection shouldn't be empty because there are many records into the table that satisfy the `where` conditions.

If I make the same select directly in SQL Server, all works fine. The anno and nomediv parameters are corrects.

```
try
   connection1.Open()
   sqlcmd = String.Format("select distinct HomeTeam from tutto  WHERE anno='{0}' AND div= '{1}' AND HomeTeam <> 'NULL'", annocampionato, nomediv(i))

   SetSqlCommand(sqlcmd, 1)
   sqlreader1 = sqlcommand1.ExecuteReader()

   Do While sqlreader1.Read() 
      If sqlreader1.HasRows Then ' 
                 nomesquadra = RTrim(sqlreader1.GetString(0))
                 ......
      End If
   Loop

   connection1.Close()

  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    connection1.Close()
End Try
```

Try to explain better: the program enters into the `WHILE` loop and `sqlreader1.hasrows` is TRUE but `sqlreader1.GetString(0)` return index out of range exception. If I change the command to `SELECT * FROM tutto`, the result is the same.

Thanks in advance

Pamela

P.S. I'll avoid to use the string concat for the release version

Comment: Please post **all** of your code.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have "If sqlreader1.HasRows Then" inside the While loop... the while loop wouldn't ever be entered unless you had results.

Comment: Also, use Parameterised queries, NOT String concartentation or String formatting.

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "the selection is empty". Empty in what way? Do you ever enter your while loop?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `AND HomeTeam IS NOT NULL` or are you actually storing the string NULL into the field?

Comment: You should also turn on Option Strict.

Comment: yes i'm using tables that can have the string "NULL" (not intended as nothing value) into that field

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is backward. Granted, the documentation is thin.

If you get one line then the following happens:

> Do While sqlreader1.Read()

returns true and reads the data.

> If sqlreader1.HasRows Then '

returns false because there is no MORE data.

It makes no sense to check HasRows in the loop. In fact, it makes no sense to check it at all - just loop over the Read() method.